# Получить количество строк по колонке?

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица orders, в ней у товара есть колонка category_id. 
Вопрос, как мне составить запрос наиболее быстрый, чтобы получить все уникальные значения категорий и количество в их записей?

к примеру то что мне нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например вот так:

```
Select category_id, count(category_id) from `orders` group by category_id
```

Comment: для EF будет так? : var c = db.Orders.OrderBy(order=> order.CategoryId).Select(order=> order.CategoryId).Count();

Comment: @dgzargo Что есть EF? ибо мне данный термин не знаком

Comment: Entity Framework

Comment: @dgzargo Незнаю, вполне возможно, мне данный фрейм использовать не приходилось.